# Power Query - Transpose unique values and get matching values in rows

Tags: excel, pivot, unique, transpose, powerquery

I am trying to transform a very simple input_table

[image]

into this output_table:

[image]

I am basically trying to:

- Get unique items in first column
- Transpose and promote these items as column headers
- Get matching values (from the second column in **input_table**) under each unique header

I am using Power Query because I need the **output_table** to dynamically update each time I add records to **input_table**, but any other dynamical solution is accepted (Array Formulas, intermediate Tables, etc...). No VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called Table1 and is structured in the way shown in the screenshot, I think this Power Query query should do what you want:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Type", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(ChangedType, {"Type"}, {{"DistinctValues", each _[Value]}}),
    Output = Table.FromColumns(GroupedRows[DistinctValues], GroupedRows[Type])
in
    Output
```

Chris

Comment: it is exactly what I needed.
elegant and concise, an amazing answer.